# Spring Cloud Config Server issue - Configuring multiple sources native and jdbc

Tags: spring, configuration, cloud

I want to connect to multiple repositories i.e native (file system) and jdbc in spring cloud config. I created a spring cloud config server with below details

application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.include=native,jdbc

spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/config,classpath:/app1, classpath:/app2,classpath:/ep
encrypt.key=abcdef


spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/configuration?useSSL=false
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.sql=SELECT properties.key, properties.value from  PROPERTIES where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and LABEL=?

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root  

spring.cloud.config.server.native.order=1
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=2
```

Irrespective of priority order it always fetches information from jdbc and not from native. 
I tried adding the last 2 properties for order to bootstrap.properties still same behavior.
Am is missing anything ? Is my configuration correct ? Please suggest

Comment: Did you try a composite profile with two sources? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#composite-environment-repositories

Answer (score 1):

in spring boostrap.yml loaded before application.yml so you declare server port,config search location and active profile configuration is good approach for this stack,so keep it simple boostrap.yml also spring cloud default profile is native

and in application-"profile".yml is have environment and  other configuration properties

and your boostrap.yml or properites like that

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: appName
  profiles:
    active: native,jdbc
  cloud:
     config:
       server:
         native:
           order: 1
           searchLocations: classpath:/config,classpath:/app1, classpath:/app2,classpath:/ep
```

and create applicaiton-jdbc.properties or yml file in same layer in boostrap.yml or properties and declare jdbc properties

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/configuration?useSSL=false'
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          order: 2
          sql: 'SELECT properties.key, properties.value from  PROPERTIES where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and LABEL=?'
  username: root
  password: root
```

and your config server configuration like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@Import({JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class})
public class ConfigServer {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, arguments);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , I tried way you mentioned by seperating out application-jdbc.yml and keeping rest in bootstrap.yml however data is always picked up from jdbc if data matches in table otherwise no data returned even if same criteria should bring data from file system.  For jdbc i am adding a dependency - <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId> , however if we remove dependency data from file system is picked up by server. Any   other suggestions

Comment: your configration is enabled for JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class  add this anotation @Import({JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class })  where you use to @EnableConfigServer

Comment: Can you share any example for using @Import({JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class }) ?  On importing JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class I am getting issues related to setting JdbcTemplate . When i do Import({JdbcEnvironmentRepository.class ,JdbcTemplate.class}) it gives  datasource issues

Comment: @AmolDeopujari I update my answer and add example code

Comment: Thanks will try your option . In the mean time i was successful in supporting both native and jdbc by  setting profile property in bootstrap as follows - spring.profiles.active=jdbc  and imported Native Repository  @Import({NativeEnvironmentRepository.class}) . Thanks for your help

Comment: @AmolDeopujari thanks in you,İf my approaches help to you please confirm to my answer :)